# Enquire about a missing bank account which was opened by my deceased uncle in or around 1978 in Italy?

Tags: bank-account, italy

I am trying to enquire about a missing bank account which was opened by deceased uncle in Italy, Milan in 1978 and I am aware he opened a bank account in that city around this time.

He made my family aware of the bank account, I am currently trying to retrieve the funds from the account, but do not know how it is possible to do this with having so little information about the account.

It would be great if there is a Law firm or some kind of agency or that are specialized in handling such cases.

Comment: first determine if that account would still exist. After a period of inactivity they might have a law that directs what the bank is supposed to do with the funds. If it is given to the local or national government it might be easy to find with very little information.  If it is still in the control of the bank, it might be harder to know what banks existed in that region of the country in the 1970's and what happened to those banks over the decades.

Answer (score 1):

Following is a company that provides the service of search property records for emigrants from Italy in your exact situation.

http://www.landfinder.it/main.asp?aff=AF0071&sid=&lng=inglese&p=

You can search by name and location. They also offer assistance and fee quotation on Skype.

I cannot vouch for the reliability of this company.

Answer (score 1):

By now, the funds on that account have almost certainly been transferred to the State. They are called [depositi dormienti](http://www.mef.gov.it/depositi-dormienti/) (sleeping accounts).

On the bright side, this probably makes things easier for you: you can [claim your funds](http://www.consap.it/fondi-e-attivita/supporto/rapporti-dormienti) with certified mail and there is a [simple search mask](http://www.consap.it/fondi-e-attivita/supporto/rapporti-dormienti/cerca-rapporto-dormiente) which only asks for information you said you have.